# Logit Transform: multidimensional generalization to add noise to simplex?

Tags: logit, transform

How to generalize the logit transform to more than one dimensions? That is, how to add noise to an arbitrary element of an $n$-dimensional probability simplex.

(1) In one dimension, we have

$L:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$

defined by

$L(p)=\frac{exp(ln\frac{p}{1-p}+\sigma\varepsilon)}{1+exp(ln\frac{p}{1-p}+\sigma\varepsilon)},$

where $\sigma\geq0$ and $\varepsilon$~$\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

(2) What if we had $p,q,r\geq0$ with $p+q+r=1$. How to use something like the logit transform to add "noise" such that $L(p)+L(q)+L(r)\geq0$ with $L(p)+L(q)+L(r)=1$?